# search_field cannot accept query from User model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

i tried to make search field to search by author in the admin panel but i got an error

```
Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
```

i follow the documentation and other stackoverflow question but it doesn't work

@model.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)



# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='content')
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

@admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Author,

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 
                    'date_published', 
                    'date_edited', 
                    'author', ]
    
    search_fields = ['title',
                     'author__user',]

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
admin.site.register(Author)
```

it works when i changed the search_field[1] to author__id,  but since it only accept id, it can't get the username. any idea how to solve it? should i make custom user model?

Comment: Do you want to search by the author's username? Can't you just use `author__user__username`?

Comment: i didn't know i can't do that! thanks a lot!

Comment: @GraceYudha: well `author__user` is a `User` object. How would you search on such an object? What field(s) of that object should you take into account?